# Video classification using CNN + LSTM combination loss isn't reducing, metrics aren't improving

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, lstm

I'm trying to build a binary classification network for videos.
Dataset class loads 16/32 frames per video along with its label.
The model is a combination of pretrained Resnet101 followed by LSTM and a Linear layer for classification.
I'm using SGD optimizer with lr=0.01, and Binary cross entropy loss as criterion. The loss hovers around 0.6 for all the epochs and the model either predicts all 0's or all 1's

Can someone go through my network architecture and training code and identify the issue. I'm adding the dataset class, model class and training script below

Note: Ignore the fact that validation and train split are same, I was trying to overfit the model on smaller subset to make sure it can learn the data

Dataset class

```
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader, Subset
import glob
from PIL import Image
import torch
import numpy as np
import random
import os
import cv2
import csv
import shutil
np.random.seed(2020)
random.seed(2020)
torch.manual_seed(2020)


class VideoDataset(Dataset):
    """
    Load and save pairs of 16 frame in .npy file
    save .npy file name and corresponding label in class var
    Can skip_frames
    Assumes that video names are not duplicated in any splits
    """
    def __init__(
            self, 
            vids_dir, 
            labels_path, 
            transform,
            cache_dir='cache',
            sequence_length=32
    ):      
        self.transform = transform
        self.vids_dir = vids_dir
        self.labels_path = labels_path
        self.cache_dir = cache_dir
        self.sequence_length = sequence_length
        self.create_cache_dir()

        # extracting 16 frames per clip, logic could vary as needed
        # current logic select 1 out of 2 frames, each clip has either 30, 60 90 or 120 frame
        self.vid_name_label_map = {}
        self.get_video_label_map()

        self.frames_label_map = [] # [{label: ['img_name1', 'img_name2', ... 16 image paths]}]
        self.get_total_frame_count()

        # log
        print(f'initiated video dataset of {vids_dir}')
    
    def create_cache_dir(self):
        if os.path.exists(self.cache_dir):
            # pass
            shutil.rmtree(self.cache_dir)
        os.makedirs(self.cache_dir, exist_ok=True)

    def get_video_label_map(self):
        with open(self.labels_path, 'r') as fp:
            csv_data = csv.reader(fp)
            for row in csv_data:
                vid_name, label = row[0], int(row[1])
                self.vid_name_label_map[vid_name] = label
        
    def get_total_frame_count(self):
        # self.ds_len = 0
        for vid_name in os.listdir(self.vids_dir):
            curr_sample_frame_label_map = {}
            curr_label = self.vid_name_label_map[vid_name.split('.')[0]]
            vid_path = os.path.join(self.vids_dir, vid_name)
            cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vid_path)
            vid_frames = int(cap.get(7))
            # samples_in_vid = vid_frames // 30 # current dataset has either 30, 60, 90, 120
            # sample_ind = 0
            frames_to_capture = np.linspace(0, vid_frames-1, self.sequence_length, dtype=np.int16)
            curr_sample_frame_label_map[curr_label] = []
            # sample_ind += 1            
            for frame_ind in range(vid_frames):
                success, frame = cap.read()
                if not success:
                    continue

                if frame_ind not in frames_to_capture:
                    continue           

                save_as = os.path.join(self.cache_dir, f'{vid_name}_{frame_ind}.jpg')
                if not os.path.exists(save_as):
                    cv2.imwrite(save_as, frame)
                curr_sample_frame_label_map[curr_label].append(save_as)

                # self.ds_len += 1           
            
            # if sequence length not met, pad with last frames 
            if len(curr_sample_frame_label_map[curr_label]) != self.sequence_length:
                for _ in range(self.sequence_length - len(curr_sample_frame_label_map[curr_label])):
                    curr_sample_frame_label_map[curr_label].append(curr_sample_frame_label_map[curr_label][-1])
            # print('current sample frames = ', len(curr_sample_frame_label_map[curr_label]))
            self.frames_label_map.append(curr_sample_frame_label_map.copy())

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.frames_label_map)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        label_img_paths_map = self.frames_label_map[idx]
        label = list(label_img_paths_map.keys())[0]
        path2imgs = label_img_paths_map[label]
        frames = []
        for p2i in path2imgs:
            frame = Image.open(p2i)
            frames.append(frame)
        
        frames_tr = []
        for frame in frames:
            frame = self.transform(frame)
            frames_tr.append(frame)
        if len(frames_tr)>0:
            frames_tr = torch.stack(frames_tr)
        label = label            
        return frames_tr, label

def collate_fn(batch):
    imgs_batch, label_batch = list(zip(*batch))
    imgs_batch = [imgs for imgs in imgs_batch if len(imgs)>0]
    label_batch = [torch.tensor(l) for l, imgs in zip(label_batch, imgs_batch) if len(imgs)>0]
    imgs_tensor = torch.stack(imgs_batch)
    labels_tensor = torch.stack(label_batch).to(dtype=torch.float32)
    return imgs_tensor,labels_tensor        

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from transforms import train_transformer

    ds = VideoDataset(
        vids_dir='dataset_merged_clips/videos',
        labels_path='dataset_merged_clips/labels.csv',
        cache_dir='cache',
        transform=train_transformer
    )
        
    ds.__getitem__(0)
    print(ds)
```

Model class

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchvision.models import resnet101


class CNNLSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes=2):
        super(CNNLSTM, self).__init__()
        self.resnet = resnet101(pretrained=True)
        self.resnet.fc = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(self.resnet.fc.in_features, 300))
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=300, hidden_size=256, num_layers=3)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(256, 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, num_classes)
        self.sig = nn.Sigmoid()
       
    def forward(self, x_3d):
        hidden = None
        for t in range(x_3d.size(1)):
            with torch.no_grad():
                x = self.resnet(x_3d[:, t, :, :, :])  
            out, hidden = self.lstm(x.unsqueeze(0), hidden)         

        x = self.fc1(out[-1, :, :])
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.sig(x)
        return x
```

Training script

```
import os
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch.nn import CrossEntropyLoss, BCELoss
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torch.optim.lr_scheduler import ReduceLROnPlateau

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

from dataset2 import VideoDataset
from dataset2 import collate_fn as rnn_collate_fn
from transforms import train_transformer
from transforms import test_transformer
from resnet_rcnn_model import DecoderRNN
from resnet_rcnn_model import ResCNNEncoder
from cnnlstm import CNNLSTM

device = torch.device("cuda:1" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# training parameters
k = 1               # number of target category
epochs = 100        # training epochs
batch_size = 4
learning_rate = 0.001
log_interval = 10   # interval for displaying training info

# pretrained weights
use_hac_pretrained_weights = False

# save model path
save_model_path = 'saved_models3'
if not os.path.isdir(save_model_path):
    os.makedirs(save_model_path)

def train(model, device, train_loader, optimizer, criterion, epoch):
    # set model as training mode
    model.train()

    train_loss = 0

    all_y = np.zeros(0, dtype=np.int64)
    all_pred_y = np.zeros(0, dtype=np.int64)

    N_count = 0   # counting total trained sample in one epoch
    for batch_idx, (X, y) in enumerate(train_loader):
        # y = y.type(torch.LongTensor)
        X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)
        N_count += X.size(0)
        
        output = model(X)
        loss = criterion(output, y.view(-1,1))
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()        
        train_loss += loss.item()

        y_pred = output.round().type(torch.int64).view(-1).cpu().numpy()
        all_pred_y = np.concatenate((all_pred_y, y_pred))
        all_y = np.concatenate((all_y, y.type(torch.int64).cpu().numpy()))

    train_loss /= (batch_idx+1)  
    print('\nEPOCH:', epoch+1, '\nTRAIN')
    print('loss:', train_loss)
    print(confusion_matrix(all_y, all_pred_y))  
    print(classification_report(all_y, all_pred_y)  )
    
    return train_loss


def validation(model, device, criterion, test_loader):
    # set model as testing mode
    model.eval()
    test_loss = 0
    all_y = np.zeros(0, dtype=np.int64)
    all_pred_y = np.zeros(0, dtype=np.int64)
    with torch.no_grad():
        for batch_idx, (X, y) in enumerate(test_loader):
            X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)
            output = model(X)

            loss = criterion(output, y.view(-1,1))
            test_loss += loss.item()                

            y_pred = output.round().type(torch.int64).view(-1).cpu().numpy()
            all_pred_y = np.concatenate((all_pred_y, y_pred))
            all_y = np.concatenate((all_y, y.type(torch.int64).cpu().numpy()))

    test_loss /= (batch_idx + 1)

    print('VAL')
    print('loss:', test_loss)
    print(confusion_matrix(all_y, all_pred_y))  
    print(classification_report(all_y, all_pred_y))    

    return test_loss

# CREATE MODEL
cnnlstm_model = CNNLSTM(num_classes=k).to(device)

val_ds = VideoDataset(
    vids_dir='dataset_merged_clips/videos',
    labels_path='dataset_merged_clips/labels.csv',
    transform=test_transformer,
    sequence_length=16
)

train_dl = DataLoader(val_ds, batch_size= batch_size,
                        shuffle=True, collate_fn= rnn_collate_fn, pin_memory=True)
val_dl = DataLoader(val_ds, batch_size= batch_size,
                        shuffle=False, collate_fn= rnn_collate_fn, pin_memory=True) 

# Combine all EncoderCNN + DecoderRNN parameters
crnn_params = cnnlstm_model.parameters()

# criterion = CrossEntropyLoss()
criterion = BCELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(crnn_params, lr=learning_rate, momentum=0.9)
lr_scheduler = ReduceLROnPlateau(optimizer=optimizer, mode='min', factor=0.5, patience=3, verbose=True)

least_test_loss = 10

for epoch in range(epochs):
    # train, test model
    epoch_train_loss = train(cnnlstm_model, device, train_dl, optimizer, criterion, epoch)
    epoch_test_loss = validation(cnnlstm_model, device, criterion, val_dl)

    # save Pytorch models of best record
    if epoch_test_loss < least_test_loss:
        torch.save(cnnlstm_model.state_dict(), os.path.join(save_model_path, 'cnnlstm_epoch{}.pt'.format(epoch + 1)))  # save motion_encoder
        torch.save(optimizer.state_dict(), os.path.join(save_model_path, 'optimizer_epoch{}.pt'.format(epoch + 1)))      # save optimizer
        print("Epoch {} model saved!".format(epoch + 1))
        least_test_loss = epoch_test_loss
```

transforms

```
h, w =224, 224
mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]
std = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]

test_transformer = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.Resize((h,w)),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize(mean, std),
            ])
```

What I tried: To train a network to classify video sequences (binary classification)
What I expected: The loss value to reduce over epochs, and metrics to improve
What happens: The loss hovers around 0.7 for 50+ epochs, metrics don't improve, hovers around 50% which is random?

Answer (score 0):

One potential problem with the `CNNLSTM` model is that the `fc` layer from the pretrained resnet model is being replaced with randomly initialized `fc` layer. This would mean that the `fc` layer has no useful weights, therefore, we must train (update its weights) it during the training process.

Currently the whole renset forward pass is run within `torch.no_grad()` context, i.e. the training process will not update weights of any layer of the resnet model, including the newly added `fc` layer. This can be fixed by removing the `with torch.no_grad():` statement, in which case all layers of resnet model will be updated. Alternatively, we can set `requires_grad` for all parameters of resnet model except the last `fc` layer to `False`:

```
class CNNLSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes=2):
        super(CNNLSTM, self).__init__()
        self.resnet = resnet101(pretrained=True)
    
        # Modify the last fully connected layer to match the desired output size
        self.resnet.fc = nn.Linear(self.resnet.fc.in_features, 300)

        # Freeze all parameters in the ResNet backbone except for the last fully connected layer
        for param in self.resnet.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = False
        for param in self.resnet.fc.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = True

        # Define the LSTM layer and the additional fully connected layers
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=300, hidden_size=256, num_layers=3)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(256, 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, num_classes)
        self.sig = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, x_3d):
        hidden = None
        for t in range(x_3d.size(1)):
            x = self.resnet(x_3d[:, t, :, :, :])
            out, hidden = self.lstm(x.unsqueeze(0), hidden)

        x = self.fc1(out[-1, :, :])
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.sig(x)
        return x

    def trainable_parameters(self):
        # Return parameters of the fully connected layers and LSTM
        return list(self.resnet.fc.parameters()) + list(self.lstm.parameters()) + list(self.fc1.parameters()) + list(self.fc2.parameters())
```

Also, update the parameters being using in optimzer:

```
crnn_params = cnnlstm_model.trainable_parameters()
```

Comment: I've made the change, but the model doesn't converge.

Comment: there could be a number of reasons the model is not converging. Try changing `lr` and optimizer to Adam.

Comment: after making the changes the best validation scores were as follows
| class | precision | recall | f1-score | support |
| ----- | --------- | ------ | -------- | ------- |
| 0     | 0.72      | 0.78   | 0.75     | 64      |
| 1     | 0.76      | 0.7    | 0.73     | 64      |

but during inference all output values are approximately 0.5, may be the loss function ended optimizing for 0.5 instead of 0 or 1

Comment: so are you still having one type of output (0 or 1) during inference?

Comment: Yes, after some iterations all outputs are defaulting to 0, even after I add more classes in dataset. I tried to overfit the model on a single batch of 8 samples over 10 iterations and it worked, but after a few batches the predictions are all 0. Also tried using weighted loss, didn't work